# Mapbox l.polygon label

Tags: label, leaflet, polygon, mapbox

I'm adding multiple polygons to a Mapbox map using:

```
L.polygon(polyPoints, polyOptions).addTo(featureGroup);
```

What's the easiest way to add labels to each polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't support labels out-of-the-box. If you want labels there is the Leaflet.Label plugin: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.label/ Once you've loaded the JS and CSS assets adding a label to a polygon is as simple as:

```
L.polygon(polyPoints, polyOptions).bindLabel('My Label').addTo(featureGroup);
```

Check the README in the repository for much more options and details:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label#leafletlabel

Comment: Two days in a row you've helped me out.  Thanks!